# Как послать команду сортировки?

Tags: xml, javascript, xslt

Помогите, пожалуйста, организовать сортировку. Работать она должна так. Пользователь видит таблицу, пользователь кликает по любому заголовку стоблца, после этого строки соответствующего столбца сортируются по возрастанию.

Как работает сортировка в xslt я знаю. Но проблема в том, что при помощи js, который я использую, чтобы начать сортировку (скрипты подключены внизу страницы), не получается добраться по dom-дереву до нужного элемента. Элементы из пространства имён xsl: не "видны".

Объясните, пожалуйста, идею. То есть что нужно сделать в общем виде.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xsl/rules.xsl"?>

<price>
    <name>Прайс 1</name>
    <item>
        <header img="img1_large.png" img_large="img1_large_large.png">Мыло хозяйственное</header>
        <percent>72</percent>
        <weight>200</weight>
        <color>Светлое</color>
        <price>8,50</price>
        <quantity>80</quantity>
    </item>
    <item>
        <header img="img1_large.png" img_large="img1_large_large.png">Мыло ординарное</header>
        <percent>75</percent>
        <weight>100</weight>
        <color>Светлое</color>
        <price>8,50</price>
        <quantity>10</quantity>
    </item>
    <item>
        <header img="img1_large.png" img_large="img1_large_large.png">Мыло туалетное</header>
        <percent>65</percent>
        <weight>300</weight>
        <color>Тёмное</color>
        <price>18,50</price>
        <quantity>30</quantity>
    </item>
</price>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1.**
Использовать уже готовое решение для сортировки HTML таблиц.

- [Jquery Datatables](http://datatables.net/)
- [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.ru/docs/)
- [sorttable](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/)
- [TSorter](http://www.terrill.ca/sorting/)
- В общем [их хватает](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/10/03/33-javascript-solutions-for-sorting-tables/)

Вот это 100% работает:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>      
        <head>
            <title> Прайс-лист очень хороший </title>            
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/blue/style.css" type="text/css" media="print, projection, screen" /> 
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Заголовок прайс листа тут</h1>

            <div class="content">
                <table id="pricetable" class="tablesorter">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Название</th>
                            <th>Процент</th>
                            <th>Масса</th>
                            <th>Цвет</th>
                            <th>Цена</th>
                            <th>Количество</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <xsl:for-each select="//item">
                            <tr>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="header"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="percent"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="weight"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="color"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="quantity"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>   
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <script src="jquery.js" />
                <script src="jquery.tablesorter.js" />
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() 
                        { 
                            $("#pricetable").tablesorter(); 
                        } 
                    ); 
                </script>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

**Вариант 2.**
Использовать сортировку средствами xslt, основанную на включении или выключении `<xsl:sort />`. Для этого вам надо будет вручную загрузить соответствующие `DOMdocument-ы`, добавить или убрать нужные `<xsl:sort />` и выполнить трансформацию.

**UPD:**
[Вот тут](http://tram.ruz.net/routes/xml/routes2001.htm) видел попытку реализовать нечто подобное. Общая идея описана выше. То-есть, вы готовите заранее преобразование, а потом его применяете к xml-ю. Только учтите, что данный код заточен под IE (Используется Microsoft.XMLDOM).

Comment: меня как раз второй вариант интересует. я его пробовал. но безуспешно. создавал в документе пустой блок и после клика на заголовке таблицы добавлял в него <xsl:sort select="percent" data-type="number" /> при помощи document.getElementById("sort").innerHtml = .........
в результате firebug показывал, что правило сортировки добавилось в документ, но самой сортировки столбца не произошло.

я разместил бы ссылки на скриншоты, но этот сайт все ссылки режет. даже на готовый сайт мой, на котором уже есть всё о чем я здесь говорю, убрал ссылку

Comment: Тогда покажите, как вы делали.

Comment: Описать, как я делал, можно только ссылкой на живой сайт. Вот она (если хэшкод не скроет) http://prozaik.16mb.com/question/soap/

Comment: Я понял. Вы несколько неправильно делаете. Этим скриптом вы внедряете xsl узел в выходное HTML дерево. Так работать не будет.

Попробуйте глянуть пример из UPD.

Comment: http://tram.ruz.net/routes/xml/routes2001.htm